# Rails YAML Fixture Error with PaperTrail gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, fixtures, paper-trail-gem

I'm trying to create a rails fixture for testing a controller that fetches versions persisted with the [paper_trail](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail) gem (7.0.1). But, I've thus far been unable to populate any versions within fixtures to test against. And, it appears that the YAML file isn't loading/is breaking other tests. Here's the contents of my `versions.yml`` file:

```
---
version_001:
  id: 1
  item_type: 'DistributionChannel'
  item_id: 1
  event: 'create'
  whodunnit: <%= User.find_by(email: 'user@example.com').id.to_s %>
  object: nil
  created_at: 2017-05-15 12:00:00.000000000 Z
  object_changes: '---\\nid:\\n- \\n- 1\\nprimary_channel:\\n- \\n- Best Buy\\nsecondary_channel:\\n- \\n- ''\ncreated_at:\\n- \\n- 2017-05-15 12:00:00.000000000 Z\\nupdated_at:\\n- \\n- 2017-05-15 12:00:00.000000000 Z\\n'
```

The schema contains the versions table with the appropriate columns btw.

Comment: Going out on a limb here, do object_changes need to be in double quotes?

Comment: What kind of error messages do you get? Is the value for `object_changes` really evaluated **twice** to get the double backslashes out of the loaded YAML (for which they are **not** escape sequences, i.e. `\\n` loads as 3 characters  ). What is your exact question? Whether there is an alternative for paper_trail? How to convert the YAML to JSON? If you can write the test using XML?

Comment: I actually don't receive an error when loading fixtures with db:fixtures:load, but there are no versions loaded when prying into the tests. I'd definitely like to continue using paper_trail. And, it was my understanding that I needed to escape the new line characters, hence the additional '\'. I'm very new to fixtures since I prefer factories. In a nutshell, I'm looking to see if there are any apparent syntax errors or other hiccups that those with paper_trail experience might know about that would prevent the fixtures from loading. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually got the fixture to load by adding the following to test_helper.rb:

`self.set_fixture_class versions: PaperTrail::Version`

And, the with following yaml syntax:

```
version_001:
  id: 1
  item_type: 'DistributionChannel'
  item_id: 1
  event: 'create'
  whodunnit: <%= ActiveRecord::FixtureSet.identify('user_example').to_s %>
  object: nil
  created_at: 2017-05-15 12:00:00
  object_changes: "---\nid:\n- \n- 1\nprimary_channel:\n- \n- Best Buy\nsecondary_channel:\n- \n- ''\ncreated_at:\n- \n- 2017-05-15 12:00:00.000000000 Z\nupdated_at:\n- \n- 2017-05-15 12:00:00.000000000 Z\n"
```

The addition to test_helper.rb is necessary because the Version table is namespaced within PaperTrail. I've seen some conflicting info about appropriate yaml syntax, so I'm hesitant to explain my theories why that yaml syntax worked (any explanations in comments would be greatly appreciated). But, hopefully this will help point someone in the right direction when testing paper_trail with Minitest and using fixtures.

Answer (score 1):

I faced with the similar issue.  When I didn't use `versions` fixture (there was no versions fixture YAML file), this caused that `versions` table was not cleared on `rake db:fixtures:load` so that this quite confused me on development environment debugging.

In order to avoid this issue, I introduced `versions` fixture as follows:

1. Locate fixture file to test/fixtures/paper_trail/versions.yml so that it is automatically loaded by rake task.
2. Writing `object_changes` data by hand is quite tedious task so that let's use `to_yaml` method to generate it as follows.  Creating and/or updating an AR generates version record so that following at command-line generates yaml file to tmp/versions.yml:

   ```
   $ rails console
   irb> File.write('tmp/versions.yml', PaperTrail::Version.all.map{|v| v.attributes}.to_yaml)
   ```
3. edit tmp/versions.yml as follows and save it to test/fixtures/paper_trail/versions.yml:

   ```
   version_001:
     item_type:  DistributionChannel
     item:       distribution_001
     event:      create
     whodunnit:  ...
     created_at: 2017-12-27 02:25:33.000000000 Z
     object_changes: "... (keep as above to_yaml generated)..."
   ```
4. Now, run `rake db:fixtures:load`!  It should load version fixture to PaperTrail::Version AR and distribution_001 record `.versions` method should contain it.

NOTE-1: `item` above is [Label Reference](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActiveRecord/FixtureSet.html)

NOTE-2: `whodunnit` should be the same.  See [Fixture label interpolation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActiveRecord/FixtureSet.html)